# wp_dropdown_categories and custom taxonomy + custom post type

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, dropdown, list, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have created custom post type called "case study"(with slug case-study), with support of custom taxonomy which is called "theme".

What i am trying to achieve? Simple dropdown, with redirect to specific taxonomy term page on option select.

The code:

```
<form 
id="category-select" 
class="category-select"
action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">

    <?php

    $args = array(
        'show_option_all'  => __( 'Choose theme', 'l-p' ),
        'hide_empty'       => 0,
        'echo'             => 0,
        'show_count'       => 0,
        'taxonomy'         => 'theme',
    );

    $select  = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
    $replace = "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>";
    $select  = preg_replace( '#<select([^>]*)>#', $replace, $select );

    echo $select;

    ?>

    <noscript><input type="submit" value="View" /></noscript>

</form>
```

Thing is, i'm getting dropdown with proper list of taxonomy terms, but when clicking on specifc option(from dropdown) it redirects me to weird pages/urls instead of actual taxonomy template page.

- I have tried saving direct links in wp settings.
- Taxonomy have proper template called taxonomy-theme.php
- The same dropdown works properly for default blog posts.
- CPT and taxonomy is created via CPT UI(i'm not really fond of it, but well, it was "required") - the support for taxonomy/cpt is checked in options.
- The slug for custom taxonomy is "theme".
- The slug for custom post type is "case-study".
- The taxonomy terms pages are present, it's just that dropdown redirects incorrectly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your code to work the expected way by adding the following three arguments to your `$args` array which you pass to [`wp_dropdown_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/):

- `name` — the `select` name as in `<select name="<here>">`, and you should set it to `theme` which is your custom **taxonomy slug**.
- `value_field` — the value of the `<option>`'s in that `select` dropdown, e.g. `<option value="<here>">`.

  And you should set the arg to `slug` so that when the form is submitted (or when a term is selected), the browser would go to `https://example.com/?theme=term-slug-here` and then WordPress redirects the browser to the correct term permalink if (and it's commonly) enabled.
- `selected` — the selected option which is a term in the custom `theme` taxonomy and because the form's destination is the term archive page, and that a term slug was specified (see the sample URL above), then set this arg to `get_query_var( 'theme' )` to get the slug of the term being queried on the page.

So try with:

```php
$args = array(
    'show_option_all' => __( 'Choose theme', 'l-p' ),
    'hide_empty'      => 0,
    'echo'            => 0,
    'show_count'      => 0,
    'taxonomy'        => 'theme',

    // Add these three args:
    'name'            => 'theme', // same as the "taxonomy" above
    'value_field'     => 'slug',  // use the term slug
    'selected'        => get_query_var( 'theme' ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom post type category dropdown with custom taxonomy slug:

```
<?php
      $obj = get_queried_object();
      $cat_slug = $obj->slug;
      wp_dropdown_categories(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'custom-post-category',
        'hide_empty' => 1,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'show_option_none' => 'All',
        'value_field' => 'slug',
        'selected' => $cat_slug  ) );
      ?>
      
<script type="text/javascript">
function($){
$(document).ready( function(){
$("#cat").change(function () {
    var selected = $("#cat option:selected");
    if(selected.val() != -1) {
      var destination = "<?php echo get_option('home');?>/custom-post-category/"; 
      if(selected.attr("class") == "level-1"){
         destination += selected.prevAll("option.level-0:first").val()+"/";
      }
      destination += selected.val()+"/";
    } else {
      var destination = "<?php echo get_option('home');?>/custom-post/";
    }
    location.href = destination;
});
});})(jQuery);
</script>
```